# How to hide the e-mail directory on outlook so users on a e-mail domain can't see all users' e-mail addresses?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange

How to make outlook hide the e-mail directory of all the e-mails of people on a domain?
If your a business owner, you don't want all your employees knowing who works for the business via the outlook or doing some auto-completes in the To section and being able to type to figure out all the possible e-mail addresses on outlook.

Comment: If Exchange cannot use the Address Book, it will not be able to send email. I do not think Exchange can do this.

Comment: @John Even if you could, Outlook caches Address Book results on each device as well. Each employee would have to manually clear that cache on all of their devices.

Comment: @pigeonburger outlook updates its address cache by default every 24 hours. This will clear out addresses the client no longer has access to

Comment: There are existing functions for limiting whether an address is shown in the address book on Exchange. I don't know if you can use access groups to control this though, as it appears to simply be a setting you apply to each account that determines whether or not the address is shown or hidden in the address book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with John, there seems to be no such a way to achieve your expectations.

In addition, I noticed that you want to not prompt your company's other email addresses when users use autocomplete in the "To" field. As a way, it is recommended that you could try to disable autocomplete in outlook to prevent users from using it when filling the "To" field.

For specific steps, please refer to ***VikiJi-MSFT***'s reply in this post: [RE: Disable Auto-Complete in Outlook 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/483411/re-disable-auto-complete-in-outlook-365.html). Hope to help you!

[image]